# Splitting every character of a string?

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to split a string into each single character. Eg:
Splitting : `"Geeta" to "G", "e", "e" , "t", "a"`
How can I do this? I want to split a string which don't have any separator 
Please help.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`String.ToCharArray()`

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method copies each character (that is, each Char object) in a string to a character array. The first character copied is at index zero of the returned character array; the last character copied is at index Array.Length – 1.

Answer (score 16):

you can use a simple for-loop with chars:

```
foreach (char ch in stringVar)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ch.ToString());
}
```

I fact you don't need to split it, because you already can acces every single char element in a string of its own.

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate over the string like this:

```
foreach (char c in myString)
{
       Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can do the following. Though it is not an effective way to do.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str ="Noman";
for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++){

System.out.println(str.charAt(i) +" ");
}
}
}
```

Comment: There is an accepted answer here and you're posting a java "solution" to a 3 year old C# question.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Nobodys perfect LOL